# How do I include module into ActionView from the lib directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

I am attempting to add a new module of custom helpers to the ActionView::Base library. I was able to get the module to load from the config/initializers directory but when I load it into the lib, the module is no longer found. I have:

```
# lib/my_templates/helper.rb
module MyTemplates
  module Helper
    def print_me
      return 'me'
    end
  end
end

ActionView::Base.send(:include, AtlasTemplates::Helper)
```

In the application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib", "#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

If I put helper.rb into the config/initializers then `<%= print_me -%>` works just fine. If I move it to it's lib location then I get `undefined local variable or method`print_me'`

I am definitely missing something here.

Comment: Sounds like autoload != require

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6797707/671432