# Access Models in subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having this problem about accessing a Model in a subfolder. I have the following file structure in my project:

```
app/models
   - accounts
     - type1.rb #Inherits from Account
     - type2.rb #Inherits from Account
     - etc.   
   - account.rb
   - user.rb
   - etc.
```

Now in user.rb I have a function that tries to create accounts of type1 or type2:

```
def function
   self.account = ::Type1.new(...)
end
```

knowing that I added to my application.rb (following http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/5/6/a-simple-alternative-to-namespaced-models) the following line:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]
```

so that the model subfolders are indeed loaded.

Now, I still get the famous `uninitialized constant Type1` error message when I call up the function. What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

The Type1 class is empty:

```
class Type1 < Account
end
```

and the Account class is straightforward:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

#======================RELATIONS======================
  belongs_to :currency
  belongs_to :organization

#======================VALIDATIONS=========================
  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :country, :presence => true
  validates :currency, :presence => true
  validates :organization, :presence => true
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
```

Comment: Nope, I tried that already. I also checked that the folder was added to the path by dumping the config.autoload_paths variable:
`C:/Users/.../lib
C:/Users/.../app/models/
C:/Users/.../app/models/accounts/`

Comment: Do u have a namespace to which type1 belongs ?

Comment: Nope, I removed it: `class Type1 < Account`

Comment: so account is just a folder name then you must try this code --  config.load_paths += Dir["#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models/*"].find_all { |f| File.stat(f).directory? }

Comment: The folder is already added properly but I tested your code anyhow (just to see) and it yields the same list of paths. So problem is still here. I guess the problem does not come from the missing path in the config.autoload_paths.

Comment: If u have used the above code u can just try Type1.new(...) instead of ::Type1.new(...). Since you dont have a namespace Type1.new(...) should work.

Comment: But the whole mystery is that it does not :) If I do Type1.new() I get `uninitialized constant User::Type1` error.

Comment: Just added them in the post's body for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17121/discussion-between-abhay-kumar-and-user1563325)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally found the thing. The idea came from this page: [Rails 3 library not loading until require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235782/rails-3-library-not-loading-until-require/6797707#6797707)

My problem was actually the file name wat not respecting the CamelCase name of the class...