# Rails: Same name for a library module and a group of controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in the process of organizing my code, so far I have successfully managed to group`controllers/helpers/views` in folders "admin", but I used to have originally a library with the same module name "admin" that I'm not being able to call anymore. (name conflict?)

The new structure:

```
Directory Structure
  -> app
    -> controllers 
      -> admin #new
        -> admin_main
        -> admin_permissions

    -> Helpers
      -> admin #new
        -> admin_main_helper
        -> admin_permissions_helper

  -> lib
    -> admin
      -> pagerduty.rb
```

I used to be able to call my library from my helpers like this:

```
module Admin::AdminMainHelper #admin:: is new
  require "./lib/admin/pagerduty.rb"

  def pager_duty
    pagerduty = Admin::PagerDuty.new() #throws error after the new structure
    @on_call = pagerduty.first_on_call()
    @counts = pagerduty.open_incidents()
  end

end
```

The error is `"uninitialized constant Admin::PagerDuty"`

Do I have to rename my library to something else? or is there a way around this?

EDIT: 
It works if I rename my library module to "AdminLib" instead of "Admin" for example. So the question is if there is a way around this.

Comment: Have you tried `::PagerDuty.new()` instead of `Admin::PagerDuty.new()`? What about `PagerDuty.new()` only?

Comment: I get "uninitialized constant PagerDuty"

Comment: Maybe I just have to rename it ... right?

Comment: no I don't think so, there must be a way to make it work. If not, it would be a bad thing that you can't have the same structure in the Helper & Lib & combine them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lies with the load path. I think the `require` should be:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/admin/pagerduty.rb"
```

Another solution, albeit a little heavy handed, is to load all of the `lib` subdirectories in the `LOAD_PATH`, eg:

In `application.rb` for `config.autoload_path`:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Comment: Yes it works! very confusing sorry, #{Rails.root} is case sensitive by the way.

Comment: If you are using Windows to run your app, you should use `Rails.root.join('lib', 'admin', 'pagerduty.rb')` (it will deal with the slash/backslash depending on the Operating System) @Newbie

Comment: we're not on windows machines. will test more.

Comment: by the way, every time I change any code I need to restart the rails server now. unlike before where I only restart when I change the code in Lib

Comment: Hopefully this link helps: http://www.williambharding.com/blog/rails/automatically-reload-modules-on-change-in-rails/

Answer (score 4):

To require dependencies **the right way in Ruby** you should:

- rename `pagerduty.rb => pager_duty.rb`
- require it with: `require 'admin/pager_duty'`

This is possible because Rails already adds your lib folder on your LOAD_PATH. This will work great in production for finished code (as libraries usually are).

But if you wish to develop your lib files in development - without the need to restart server each time you make a modification, you can change your setup like that:

- add this line to you `config/application.rb`:

  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
- remove any explicit require statements of lib files inside controllers or models (any app/* file)

This will work good as well. **But it is a common antipattern**. Because:

- The lib code should be completely independent of your app so you can share it among applications. And if you are using the autoloading mechanism it implies it is a *first-class* citizen of your application. In this case it is much better to set up a new folder inside app (e.g. app/tools) and set up autoloading for it. Otherwise you can end up with a cluttered lib folder filled with app dependent code. More info [here](http://blog.lunarlogic.io/2013/declutter-lib-directory/).
- Autoloading will not work for classes that are already defined or are defined in multiple places (e.g. monkeypatches). More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235782/rails-3-library-not-loading-until-require/6797707#6797707)

Comment: Sure. No problem with class name.

Comment: by the way, every time I change any code I need to restart the rails server now. unlike before where I only restart when I change the code in Lib

Comment: yeah correct I used to restart the server when I change the lib folder which was totally okay, but now it's whenever I change anything in any controller! very weird.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291542/rails-nameerror-uninitialized-constant-error-after-modifying-controller-code

Comment: I think you might have some inconsistencies in the naming of files and models/controllers. Which can break autoloading of app classes. Do you really have the controller code in admin/admin_main.rb? It should be admin/admin_main_controller.rb. That's definately not OK. And the controller name is then Admin::AdminMainController, right?