# "NameError, uninitialized constant" error after modifying controller code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was able recently to organize my code by grouping everything into folders. 
I had an issue with having the same "group name" for both my group of controllers under the `app/` directory and my module under the `lib/` directory but I was able to fix by following this:

[Rails: Same name for a library module and a group of controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277055/rails-same-name-for-a-library-module-and-a-group-of-controllers/18277997?noredirect=1#comment26828781_18277997)

I also know that whenever you change your `lib` code, you need to restart the rails server which is totally fine by me.

But after the recent re-organization, every time I change the code in the controllers, I get the following error!!!

```
NameError at /admin
uninitialized constant Admin::PagerDuty
```

and to resolve it, I simply restart the server!!

Any advice?!

EDIT: STRUCTURE:

Controller `main_controller.rb` is under `app/controllers/admin`

```
class Admin::MainController < ApplicationController
end
```

Helper `main_helper.rb` is under `app/helpers/admin`

```
module Admin::MainHelper
      require "admin/pager_duty.rb"

      def pager_duty
        pagerduty = Admin::PagerDuty.new()
        @on_call = pagerduty.on_call()
        @counts = pagerduty.open_incidents()
      end
end
```

lib `pager_duty.rb` is under `lib/admin`

```
module Admin 
  class PagerDuty
   ....
  end
end
```

Comment: So are you using autoloading for lib classes? Or explicit requires without autoloading?

Comment: explicit, I'll edit the question to add more info.

Comment: You should not have to restart your server in development mode with the Rails default settings. To autoload your ruby file under the lib directory, add the following to your `config/application.rb` config file: `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

Comment: The problem is not with restarting after changing lib code, it's with changing any code any where.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try changing

```
require "admin/pager_duty.rb"
```

to

```
require_dependency "admin/pager_duty.rb"
```

in your module.

Comment: It's Rails internal method, regular `require` doesn't reload changes hence `uninitialized constant` error.

Comment: I only faced this after re-organizing my files! thanks anyways