# Heroku not running migrations due to ruby module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am unable to run migrations in Heroku, which I believe is due to a module I created in my `lib` directory. After executing the command `heroku run rake db:migrate` I receive the below error:

`uninitialized constant ApplicationController::PgTools`
`/app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:4:in <class:ApplicationController>`

Line 4 of the Application controller is `include PgTools`, which is there to gain access to methods within the PgTools module I created.

Despite the heroku migration failing, I am able to run `rake db:migrate` in my local dev environments without fail (please note that both environments utilize postgres databases).

I also have the following two lines in my application.rb file

`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

`config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]`

Comment: you may need to `gem install pgtools` on your heroku instance.

Comment: it seems that `pgtools` file was not deployed to heroku..was the file added to commit before deploying?

Comment: No luck. Re-ran `bundle install` and am still receiving the same error.

Comment: @tihom Yep, I did a fresh commit before deploying

Comment: just checking as I sometimes forget to run `git add .` needed to add newly added files

Comment: Have you modified your `config.autoload_paths` to include `lib` in development.rb but not in production.rb?

Comment: @carolclarinet I have updated my question. I have the appropriate lines in application.rb - do they also need to be development.rb and production.rb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the error by renaming `Pg_Tools.rb` to `pgtools.rb` and modifying all `include PgTools` statements to `include Pgtools`

Links that I used in the troubleshooting process are shown below

[Rails 3 library not loading until require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235782/rails-3-library-not-loading-until-require)

http://www.williambharding.com/blog/technology/rails-3-autoload-modules-and-classes-in-production/