# How to load stuff in /lib in a thread safe way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, autoload, rails-api

I tried `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]` and `config.eager_load_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]` but keep getting the `uninitialized constant` error.

I assume this has to do with `dependency_loading` being disabled as `config.threadsafe!` is now the default in Rails 4.

So what's the proper way and thread safe way to eager/autoload stuff from your /lib directory?

Update: The /lib structure

lib/car.rb:

```
module Car
  CAR_TYPES = %w[volvo saab]
end
```

lib/car/volvo.rb:

```
module Car
  class Volvo
  end
end
```

The error thrown is `NameError (uninitialized constant Car::CAR_TYPES)`

Update 2: `rails c`:

```
Car.class 
=> Module
Car::CAR_TYPES
=> NameError: uninitialized constant Car::CAR_TYPES
```

Update 3: Interestingly enough, `Car::Volvo.new` works, but Car::CAR_TYPES isn't possible to reference.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `uninitialized constant` error? Are you sure all the conventions are followed to allow the constant to load?

Comment: @gmile: Updated with more specifics. Please note that I'm using the `rails-api`.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops. My application was actually called Car as well and weirdly that namespace was already in use `Car.constants => [:Application]`. Changing the `module Car` to something else solved the problem and I was able to reference `Cars::CAR_TYPES` again.

Since `Car` was already defined (in `application.rb`), autoloading doesn't even try to load `lib/car.rb`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6797707/377920 for in-depth explanation.